# problem with send() function using socket in python

Tags: python, sockets

I'm using socket in python between 2 laptop to send informations. But I have an error and i can't resolve it. (I'm a debutant in python). The problem is when i trierd to send information with send() function

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client.py", line 60, in <module>
    client.send(GetMyInfo.scan())
TypeError: send() argument 1 must be string or buffer, not None
```

Maybe the error is due my function Getinfo ?
I'm using a class with functions (listinfo() here).
Thx

Here is the code :

```
import socket
import subprocess
import os,sys
#==========================================================================================

#creation d'une classe pour rendre le programme oriente objet
class GetInfo:
    infos = os.uname()
    currentUser = os.getlogin()
    rep_actuel = os.getcwd()
    myDirectory = os.listdir("/Users/")

    def listInfo(self):
        #afficher des informations sur le systeme
        print "Informations du systeme :{} ".format(GetInfo.infos)
        #afficher l'utilisateur actuel
        print "Current user : {} \n".format(GetInfo.currentUser)
        #afficher le path du repertoire actuel
        print "Repertoire actuel : {} \n".format(GetInfo.rep_actuel)

    def scan(self):
        print "Liste de tous les repertoires dans Users/"
        #on liste toutes les directories et sous directories
        for file in GetInfo.myDirectory:
            print file

#instance de l objet GetInfo (creation de l'objet)
GetMyInfo = GetInfo()
# afficage des infos de l'objet
#GetMyInfo.listInfo()
#GetMyInfo.scan()
#==========================================================================================
# on cree un objet socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print "Socket successfully created"

# reservation d'un port specifique
port = 12345

# contient le nom d hote et le numero du port
#identifiant le serveur auquel on veut se connecter.
s.bind(('127.0.0.1', port))
print "socket binded to %s" %(port)

# activation du mode ecoute
# avec un nombre maximum de connexions qu il peut recevoir sur ce port sans les accepter
s.listen(5)
print "socket is listening"


#==========================================================================================

# gestion des erreurs
while True:
   # on etabli la connection avec le client
   client, addr = s.accept()
   print 'Got connection from', addr

   # send the informations about the victim.
   client.send(GetMyInfo.scan())

   print client.recvfrom(2048)

# on ferme la connection
s.close()
```

Comment: `GetInfo.scan()` does not return anything

Comment: `GetMyInfo.scan()` just prints filenames on the terminal. What are you expecting to send to the socket?

Comment: i would like to send the result of the function scan to the another device with the send() function